# Export type not matching variable type

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript project with a file that loads env variables and export it:

const.ts:

```
const {
  VARIABLE0, // type of VARIABLE0 is string | undefined
  VARIABLE1,
} = process.env;

if (!VARIABLE0 || !VARIABLE1) {
  throw new Error('Invalid env');
}

console.log(VARIABLE0); // type of VARIABLE0 is string
console.log(VARIABLE0.length);

export {
  VARIABLE0, // type VARIABLE0 is string | undefined
  VARIABLE1,
};
```

I don't understand why the exported type is `string | undefined` because before, I check that it is defined. On VS Code If I hover on `VARIABLE0` after the check, it is `string` but if I hover on the export, it is `string | undefined`. It is anoying on other part of my code that uses this variables because I have to add `?` and `!` in many places (for instance `const length = VARIABLE0?.length!` instead of `const length = VARIABLE0.length`).

Is there a way to export it as `string` and not `string | undefined`?

One way I see is:

```
const {
  VARIABLE0: VARIABLE0_TEMP, VARIABLE1: VARIABLE1_TEMP,
} = process.env;

if (!VARIABLE0_TEMP || !VARIABLE1_TEMP) {
  throw new Error('Invalid env');
}

const VARIABLE0 = <string>VARIABLE0_TEMP;
const VARIABLE1 = <string>VARIABLE1_TEMP;

export {
  VARIABLE0, VARIABLE1,
};
```

But it's probably not the best solution (it is quite verbose and I actually have around 10 variables to export like this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to narrow `process.env`. For example:

```
function validateConfig<T extends string>(
    env: NodeJS.ProcessEnv,
    required: readonly T[],  // readonly allows arg to be const-asserted
): asserts env is NodeJS.ProcessEnv & Record<T, string> {
    const missing = required.filter((envVar) => !(envVar in env));
    if (missing.length > 0) {
        throw new Error(`missing required env vars: ${missing.join(", ")}`);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this like:

```
validateConfig(process.env, [
    "VARIABLE0",
    "VARIABLE1",
]);
```

and either the error gets thrown or `process.env.VARIABLE0` and `process.env.VARIABLE1` are both `string`, so you can then e.g.:

```
const { VARIABLE0, VARIABLE1 } = process.env;

export {
  VARIABLE0, // type VARIABLE0 is string
  VARIABLE1,
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

**Note** that if the `required` argument is typed as `string[]` the result will be `NodeJS.ProcessEnv & Record<string, string>`, i.e. it tells the compiler that every possible environment variable will exist - either inline the list of required variables or type it `as const` to get the narrower string union array/tuple type.